# while loop in R challenge

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 columns which consists of a boolean column and values.I will like to find the sum of the F value using while loop.Coe shown below but giving error:

```
 sum <- 0
FM <- 0
 idx <- 1
while ( idx <= nrow(dataset)){
if(subset(dataset,boolean=="F")){
sum <- sum + dataset [ idx,"value" ]
FM <- FM + 1

}

  idx <- idx + 1
}
 print(sum)
```

error message is : Error in idx : object 'idx' not found

Comment: `if` requires a single logical, this code is very likely to give multiple values, and I have no idea if those values will be logical.

Comment: This might be easier for us to understand if you make this question reproducible. This includes sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`) and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Thank you for your response.example shown below:data.frame(boolean= T,F,T,T,F....,value=8,16,4,12,9,.....).Expected output is to sum the value for F using while loop

Answer (score 0):

If you count `sum` of logical values, you get count how many `TRUE` values are present. Since in this case as you want to count number of `FALSE` values we can negate the values and then use `sum`.

```
sum(!df$boolean)
#[1] 2
```

---

However, I guess you want this in a `while` loop. You can iterate over every value in `boolean` column, check if it is `FALSE` and increment the count.

```
i <- 1
FM <- 0
while(i <= nrow(df)) {
  if(!df$boolean[i]) 
     FM <- FM + 1
   i <- i + 1
}
FM
#[1] 2
```

We can also do this without `if` condition

```
while(i <= nrow(df)) {
   FM <- FM + !df$boolean[i]
   i <- i + 1
}
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(boolean= c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),value=c(8,16,4,12,9))
```